# IQueryable from runtime type with possibility to apply Where and Select

Tags: c#, linq, devexpress, iqueryable, dynamictype

I have to generate `IQueryable` from runtime type to feed it to a component. This component dynamically loads the data, so `IEnumerable` is not an option.

```
Type genericType = typeof(XPQuery<>).MakeGenericType(myRuntimeType);
IQueryable dataSource = (IQueryable)Activator.CreateInstance(genericType, 
                                                    new[] { NewOrmSession() });
```

This works just fine, but I can not apply nor `Where` nor `Select` because it is not using generic.

Any other approach is possible, since I only need to get `IQueryable` with Where and Select as output from method that accepts runtime type and, in a way, structured where clause.

Comment: What do you intend to pass to the Where and Select methods?  If you don't know the element type at compile time, you will be unable to create expressions to select values from the elements.

Comment: That is not true. You can use the Expression-Api to create everything you need for a Select() based on the runtime-Type.

Comment: I pass three things to the method. 
One is type of orm entity that is qoing to be queried. 
Second is list of columnns that I want to have.
Third is Where clause as a list of column + operator + (another column / some value)

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [DynamicLinq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed with that code that I posted. Just added Dynamic Linq library and got .Where and .Select with string parameter and params object array.
Then I can do something like:
`dataSource.Select("new( FirstName as Name, LastName , Salary)");`
and also
`dataSource.Where("Salary > @0", 1000)`
Also OrderBy is working as well.
So it is solved.